# Why command ran in Databricks notebook took more time than its jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I run below code in Databricks notebook, it spawns 3 jobs. I've checked them in Spark UI, it took them about 2~ seconds to complete (there are no orchestration delays or anything like that). However the command lasts for about 30s. Where is the "missing" execution time?

```scala
import scala.util.Random
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")

var states = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
var items = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
val rnd = new scala.util.Random(42)

states += (0 -> "AZ", 1 -> "CO", 2-> "CA", 3-> "TX", 4 -> "NY", 5-> "MI")
items += (0 -> "SKU-0", 1 -> "SKU-1", 2-> "SKU-2", 3-> "SKU-3", 4 -> "SKU-4", 5-> "SKU-5")

val usersDF = (0 to 1000000).map(id => (id, s"user_${id}", s"user_${id}@databricks.com", states(rnd.nextInt(5))))
 .toDF("uid", "login", "email", "user_state")

val ordersDF = (0 to 1000000)
 .map(r => (r, r, rnd.nextInt(10000), 10 * r* 0.2d, states(rnd.nextInt(5)), items(rnd.nextInt(5))))
 .toDF("transaction_id", "quantity", "users_id", "amount", "state", "items")

val usersOrdersDF = ordersDF.join(usersDF, $"users_id" === $"uid")

usersOrdersDF.show(false)
```

[Jobs created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BOp1.png)

[Jobs duration in Spark UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrBud.png)